# can we pass array to htmlentities() in php

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

Actually, I am fetching records from DB. Few of the records contain some special mathematical characters created by WIRIS plugin of ckeditor. I have an array of records, few of records contain such special mathematical characters which displays like �. I want to replace these characters by the actual ones used. I'm putting one snippet of output for the reference here:

```
 Array ( [answer_id] => 574146 [answer_question_id] => 74881 [answer_text] => 54��C [answer_file] => [answer_description] => [answer_is_right] => 0 )
```

The special character here should be µ. How should I show µ in HTML as well?
Please help me to resolve this issue. I tried htmlentities() and htmlspecialchars() but both are giving blank screen output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You either want to [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) or [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) depending on whether you want the result as a string or an array of strings.

Comment: Blank screen means your error reporting isn't setup properly. On that background I don't understand all the upvotes. Read about proper error reporting settings here: http://www.phptherightway.com/, and then tell us the errors you get, if there is still a problem.

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/#error_reporting

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array("micro" => "µ");

$value = array_map(function ($e) {
    return htmlentities($e, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}, $arr);

print_r($value);
```

Works as expected for me?

**edit**: If they are literally displaying as � then I would check to see if your database has UTF8 character encoding setup correctly for the tables.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `htmlentities($e, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');`? Since this appears to be character encoding issue, you would want `htmlentities()` to use the correct charset.

Comment: Actually that sounds right. Changing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply `htmlentities` to all *elements* of your array:

```
array_map("htmlentities", $you_array);
```